# How do I connect 1 inch PVC to 1/2 inch PEX?

Tags: plumbing

I've got 1inch PVC at my main and want to run 1/2 inch PEX but can't figure out what I need to do to get this done. I'm completely diy with minimal plumbing experience.

Comment: Are you plumbing the entire house? You wouldn't do so with a single 1/2" PEX line unless it's a very small house with only a few fixtures. A little more context here would help us to make the answer useful. Just adapting from 1" PVC to 1/2" PEX is easy, pick a common threaded size like 3/4 MIP/FIP and use the adapters to that size for each pipe type. That feels like an incomplete answer though to an incomplete question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's water heater 1 bathroom kitchen sink and washer

Comment: I am literally at the 1 inch PVC main and nothing else has been plumbed but I have 1/2 inch PEX rolls?

Comment: As mentioned, you'll want at least 3/4 to and from the water heater, unless you enjoy having the water slow to a trickle. Depending on your tooling and preferences that can be PVC or PEX - when you get near, and through, the water heater you'd need to switch PVC to CPVC. PEX should be fine; Unless your code requires metal piping within some distance of the heater, which mine does.

Answer (score 2):

This seems unwise, on the face of it, lacking further detail.

You normally do NOT want to chop the pipe size down to 1/4 the area (which half the diameter is) for your main feed, as it will cause excessive pressure drop. 1/2" lines are suitable for individual fixtures. They are ludicrously small for all the water in your entire house.

One approach to doing that is to adapt to a manifold with multiple 1/2" PEX outlets. You can buy such a thing pre-made, or you can make such a thing from PVC or PEX. The home-made version could be 1" PVC with 1" slip X 1/2"FTP X 1" tees with 1/2" MPT to PEX valves screwed in to each side port.

You'll generally want at least 3/4" to and from your water heater - again, you can go to 1/2" for individual fixtures. A fairly common approach is to split a 1" feed into a 3/4" to the water heater, and another 3/4" for the cold water feeds, then go to 1/2" for individual lines. Something like this sketch I made.

[image: Sketch of a "normal" layout for the items described, by me.]

Anyway, generally you put a pipe thread adapter on the PVC (Male or Female - MPT or FPT) and a mating pipe thread adapter to PEX at the size you want, which may or may not require a pipe thread size reducer in between, depending on how hard you shop.